# java if action and return

Tags: java, if-statement, return, action

I would like to write clean and fast code to evaluate some condition, do action if condition was true and return that condition value.

I have following options so far:

**Option 1:**

```
public boolean method() {
    if (...condition...) {
        action();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
public boolean method() {
    boolean actionNecessary = ...condition...;
    if (actionNecessary) {
        action();
    }
    return actionNecessary;
}
```

**Option 3:**

```
 public boolean method() {
        return ifDoReturn(...condition..., () -> {
            action();
        });
    }
```

*With helper method:*

```
public static boolean ifDoReturn(boolean condition, Runnable action) {
    if (condition) {
        action.run();
    }
    return condition;
}
```

The first option is longest, the second is shorter and also fast, the third is shortest but tricky and without compiler optimization also slow one.

Thanks for any help

Comment: This depends on many factors. Does your company have a standard to follow? Who will be maintaining? Is this a one-off program? There is no good response, because it is a case-by-case basis.

Comment: The second one is easy and readable. Use it.

Comment: Yes, but maybe appropriate name for helper method can help significantly.

Comment: I would lean towards the second option, but could live with the first option.  I think the last option is not as readable as the other two options and therefore would not consider it a good alternative.

Comment: do not make simple things overcomplicated (applies for third solution), first method has redundant else, since it can be easily rewritten as second method, thus I would choose second approach. If you are interested in readable code see the book _Clean Code_.

Comment: Pick the one that you and your team mates find most readable and natural. The compiler is probably able to even out any (minor) performance differences. For myself, I wouldn’t want to separate some of it into a helper method, but if you think it’s fine, go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Premature optimization is the root of all evil."* - Donald Knuth

I believe you're overthinking this. The JVM is smart enough to handle trivial "micro-optimizations". In simple `if...else` logic, one should typically follow the software development standards laid forth by their team. You'll be hard-pressed to find notable performance gains regardless of your approach. If the code is called often, the Just-in-Time compiler ("JIT") will compile it to object code, anyway.

That all said, in my own opinion, Option #2 is clearest.

For what it's worth, [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077647/build-ci-sdlc/make-java-fast--optimize-.html) is a deeper examination of Java optimization techniques; most importantly, covering **when and why to optimize**.

Comment: Thanks to all for voting for #2. Anyway I'm missing more syntactic sugar to express nicely such common patterns in Java. I accept this answer because it's only response written as an answer :).

Comment: Check out the books Effective Java by Joshua Bloch, and Clean Code by Robert Martin. Most Java teams worth their salt should be following these rules of thumb.